# How to resume MediaPlayer when paused

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I want the MediaPlayer music to be paused when the app is minimized, and to resume from the same point when it's restored, but I can't do it, every time it starts from the beggining...

Here's what I have:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
MediaPlayer music;
int length;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    music = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.song);
    music.setLooping(true);
    music.start();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    music.pause();
    length = music.getCurrentPosition();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    music.start();
    music.seekTo(length);
}
}
```

Comment: like the Home button is pressed, or the Back button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

U seem to have put the statements in the wrong sequence, try this instead:

```
music.seekTo(length);
music.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the last position first, then start playing again. Do this:

```
music.seekTo(length);
music.start();
```

Comment: Just tried it, it only works when I press the Home button, and when I rerunn the app it starts from the point where it was, but if I close it with the Back button, it starts from the beggining. I also tried adding onStop() to save the state

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer add onStop(), onResume() and onStart(), methods work as u expect.

Comment: Only works when the Home button is pressed, but with the Back button still nothing, and I added more methods, here's the new code http://pastebin.com/0VEsnrhQ

Comment: I am testing it on 4.0.4 on my phone

Comment: instead of Main.this in the statement music = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.song);try using :  getApplicationContext()

Comment: same thing, still doesn't resume when being exited with the Back button

Comment: I guess when you exit the app using back button the application is destroyed and once again being created when u click on app icon. So, if u still want to persist state, store the value of length in SharedPreferences.

Comment: oh, if that's so then it would probably be better to let it be destroyed, being able to resume when being minimized with Home button would be enough

Comment: whatever, but someone might find the question using the Search.
thank you